# JavaFX - how to override component's drawing behaviour?

Tags: javafx

I have a TableView and one column contains buttons. When I press the button a line is created and I drag the mouse to draw the line to another button.

The line starts and ends at the center of each button, however, I need the line to display BEHIND the buttons, yet over the table.

In Swing I would simply override the paint method of any component and write any custom graphics drawing before actually painting the button.

How can I achieve the same thing using JavaFX?

Comment: Please include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of [`Node.toFront()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#toFront--) and [`Node.toBack()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#toBack--).